# Почему в цикле while не работают инлайн кнопки?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, бот

Пишу Телеграмм бота на aiogram и столкнулся с такой проблемой: При работе с циклом `while` и с использованием в нем команды `time.sleep()`, не срабатывают инлайн кнопки.

```py
@dp.message_handler(state=task1.task1_1)
async def f_task1_1(msg: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data_task:
        data_task['task1_1'] = msg.text
    con_data_task = await state.get_data()
    global task1_1
    task1_1 = con_data_task.get('task1_1')
    done_task1_1 = False
    done1_1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    done1_1.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Сделал', callback_data='done1_1'))
    while done_task1_1 == False:
        await bot.send_message(ID_us1, task1_1, reply_markup=done1_1)
        time.sleep(5)
```

И вот тот самый callback:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler()
async def callback(call):
   if call.data == 'done1_1':
     done_task1_1 = True
```

Comment: В `callback()` функции таже нужно объявить `global done_task1_1`

Comment: Нельзя обычный `sleep` в обработчиках событий использовать. Попробуйте `await asyncio.sleep(5)`, чтобы управление возвращалось из обработчика и остальные штуки могли работать. Не факт, что именно так правильно, но копать нужно куда-то в эту сторону - в асинхронный `sleep`.

Comment: CrazyElf, все работает! Спасибо большое!